# Access eclipse workspace in headless plugin

Tags: eclipse

I create a headless Plugin for eclipse and need To access the workspace.
Did anyone has a API docs or other information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()` will give you the `IWorkspace`.

You need to specify the `-data <workspacelocation>` parameter to your headless app. You can check that this has been specified with something like:

```
  final Location instanceLoc = Platform.getInstanceLocation();
  if (instanceLoc == null || !instanceLoc.isSet()) {
    // handle error here
  }
```